# Naturalization: No divorce papers

Tags: immigration, naturalization

I will apply for naturalization soon. I answered the question of martial status as divorced (this is the real situation), but I have no divorce documents to provide because both (me and my ex-wife) are living apart in two different countries. I do have marriage papers.

So, is there any problem with not providing divorce documents? 
What should I do if there is a problem?

Edit #1: I and my ex-wife are Iraqi nationals. After researching, I think I will change my answer to separated because I have no papers of divorce. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: "Living apart in different countries" is separation, not divorce. Either you have been divorced and there must be some paperwork evidence of that, or you're not divorced.

Comment: It's not obvious that there is some paperwork, depending on jurisdiction and e.g. is this *talaq*. In that circumstance, you may need to hire a specialist lawyer sort out what would constitute acceptable documentation, e.g. a letter.

Comment: Adding the relevant countries would assist in getting a realistic answer.

Comment: Adding onto @MarkJohnson comment; Specifically where (what country) and how you were married and where and how divorced  (court, religious ceremony, both, neither?). And where trying to be naturalized (U.S.A.?)

Comment: @Yousif Alazzawi User6726 is right: You need to talk to an experienced immigration attorney. Only someone experienced will be able to tell you what documents will/won't work, or what can happen if you check "separated" when you are actually divorced. Not telling the truth on immigration documents can be used against you in the future. Non-immigration attorneys can speculate about these issues; only an immigration attorney can say for sure.